# How can my users interact with Safe without goin out of my dApp interface?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have an application that requires users to initiate transaction from their multi signature and other members to approve that transaction inside of the dapp interface without navigating the gnosis safe interface.

Can anyone help me how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The high-level overview of the possible flow: there are actually 3 stages you have to go through:

1. **Transaction creation.**
   You can manually prepare the Transaction and get the Transaction Hash, which must be signed by the required parties.
2. **Confirmation transport.**
   This depends on your dApp and the business logic.

   2.1 You could send the transaction and the hash to the Gnosis Service. The pros: all parties will see the transaction in the pending Tab of the gnosis service. They can also use mobile apps to review and sign the transaction.

   2.2 You can store the transaction at your backend, and in some way show the transaction to other participants to sign the transaction hash
3. **Transaction submission.** After you have collected all the confirmations off-chain you are ready to send the tx on-chain.